# when my ethernet cable is plugged in xbmc hangs on the start up screen

Tags: xbmc

New to the UBUNTU scene .Purchased a small PC from a friend which is running UBUNTU 14.40
It has XBMC installed. If I boot up with the ethernet cable attached The screen goes to the XBMC splash screen then hangs their. If I boot without the Ethernet cable the screen goes through to XBMC with all the Movie Music etc. Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere. Any help would be most appreciated
Thanks
Ian

Comment: Did your friend add a now non-existent network drive/path to the settings?

Comment: HiI believe he w as using a NAS to send his files to the machine

Answer (score 0):

In case we move an installation of Ubuntu or xbmx to another network we need to clear/update all references made to network devices.

These may be in different locations, and they may be adressed differently (e.g. UPnP shares, Samba shares, other network shares). For xbmc look in the music and video library references, and in general services/settings.

For Ubuntu we also may have a refence to a network share in the file `/etc/fstab`, which should then be removed.

Comment: Was speaking to my friend earlier .Apparently he had some trouble installing his network and had to do some work arounds this might be the cause of my problem will follow the advice and try and remove the older network settings

Comment: Hi Guys. Think the problem with the Ethernet cable is solved. My friend logged in to my PC remotely and after sending some commands the issue seems to be fixed. Appreciate all the replies and thanks for all advice